# How can I find the angle between two contours in Python+Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, angle

I'm trying to find the angle between the two contours in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw1Aa.jpg) image. However the center point of the contour far right is twitching all over the place. I'm using this code:

```
if len(contours) > 1:
    cnt1 = contours[0]
    cnt2 = contours[1]
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt1)
    M1 = cv2.moments(cnt1)
    M2 = cv2.moments(cnt2)
    if area > 30:
        cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 255), 3)
        X1_px = int(M1['m10'] / M1['m00'])
        Y1_px = int(M1['m01'] / M1['m00'])
        X2_px = int(M2['m10'] / M1['m00'])
        Y2_px = int(M2['m01'] / M1['m00'])
        cv2.circle(frame, (X1_px, Y1_px), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.circle(frame, (X2_px, Y2_px), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)

        if (X2_px-X1_px) != 0:
            angle = math.atan((Y2_px-Y1_px)/(X2_px-X1_px))
            angle = int(angle * (180 / math.pi))
            print(angle)
```

I think the cnt1, cnt2 part of my code is causing the problem, I don't know how openCV orders the contours in this array.

Can anyone help me fix this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have filtered the contours based on area etc and at last you have only 2 contours left:

[image]

Now for both the contours, simply get the centre point calculate the angle as:

```
import cv2
import math


def get_center(contour):
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    return cX, cY


def get_angle(p1, p2):
    return math.atan2(p1[1] - p2[1], p1[0] - p2[0]) * 180/math.pi


img = cv2.imread("./binary_img.png", 0)
i, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
if len(contours) == 2:
    center_1, center_2 = get_center(contours[0]), get_center(contours[1])
    print get_angle(center_1, center_2)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much.
I have one more question: What's different in your script that fixed my problem?